# Changing Navigation Bar Back Button thickness

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I looked everywhere and can't seem to find how to change the thickness of the navigation bar's back button text. I want it to be thinner.

Also, while we are talking about thickness, how would you go about changing the navigation bar's title thickness as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the font style by adjusting the `titleTextAttributes` on the navigation bar and the back-button item.

## Default Style (iOS 8)

[image]

## Adapting Size and Thickness (iOS < 8.2)

Prior to iOS version 8.2 the only way to adjust the weight of a font is to choose one of its variants like `HelveticaNeue-Light` or `HelveticaNeue-Bold` or by using

```
UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(_ fontSize: CGFloat)
```

There is, however, no equivalent `lightSystemFontOfSize` factory function. To reduce the weight and size of the back button and title text you could use something like this (inside a presenting view controller)

```
let rootController = UIViewController()
rootController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back",
    style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
rootController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(
    [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 15)!],
    forState: .Normal)

let detailController = UIViewController()
detailController.title = "Title"

let navController = UINavigationController()
navController.viewControllers = [rootController, detailController]
navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)!]

presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

which produces the following style

[image]

## Adapting Size and Thickness (iOS >= 8.2)

Since iOS version 8.2 you can initialize system fonts with a weight attribute.

```
UIFont.systemFontOfSize(_ fontSize: CGFloat, weight weight: CGFloat)
```

There is a set of predefined weight constants that can be found in [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Font_Weights).

Building upon the previous example you could do something like this

```
let rootController = UIViewController()
rootController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back",
    style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
rootController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(
    [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15, weight: UIFontWeightThin)],
    forState: .Normal)

let detailController = UIViewController()
detailController.title = "Title"

let navController = UINavigationController()
navController.viewControllers = [rootController, detailController]
navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightLight)]
```

which ultimately results in a style like this

[image]

Comment: How would you go about adjusting the thickness of the button icon itself?

Comment: @Chris you mean the back arrow? I Think that's only ppossible with a custom icon.